# Get last value when click

Tags: jquery

I have created a string variable with an initial value. Each time I click in a button this value change. I have created a different button to get the last value of my variable, but each time I click it returns me the initial value.

How can I get the last value of my variable ?

```
<button id='button1'>button1</button>
<button id='button2'>button2</button>
<button id='buttonSpecific'>buttonSpecific</button>
<script>
    var varState = "Initial value" ;

    $("#button1").click(function() {
        var varState = "button1" ;
        console.log(varState)
    });

    $("#button2").click(function() {
        var varState = "button2" ;
        console.log(varState)
    });

    $("#buttonSpecific").click(function() {   
        // Get the last value 
        console.log(varState)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var varState = "Initial value";

$("#button1").click(function() {
  varState = "button1"; //dont initialize again remove var
});
$("#button2").click(function() {
  varState = "button2"; //dont initialize again remove var
});
$("#buttonSpecific").click(function() {
  // Get the last value 
  console.log(varState)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button1'>button1</button>
<button id='button2'>button2</button>
<button id='buttonSpecific'>button3</button>
```

Dont initialize the variable again

Comment: @GeoGyro glad it helps you can tick the check mark to mark this post as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

In every click event you are initializing variable again thats why this problem is occuring, to declare variable as global you just need to declate variable once above all script.

```
<button id='button1'>Button 1</button>
<button id='button2'>Button 2</button>
<button id='buttonSpecific'>Button Specific</button>

<script>
var varState = "Initial value" ;

$("#button1").click(function() {
  varState = "button1" ;
});
$("#button2").click(function() {
   varState = "button2" ;
});

$("#buttonSpecific").click(function() {   
  console.log(varState)
});
</script>
```